# Include external code on a web page ( php include() or get_header() )

Tags: php, html, include, xampp, get-headers

I've started creating a custom html page for the first time and i've hit a bump. The code in the header will be the same in all my pages , so i want to put it in an external file (header.php) and just put 1 line of code in all my pages to link to it but it doesn't seem to be working .

- Note - I want to include just basic html code ( not a function ) - i'm thinking that's why its not working but not sure.

HTML file :

```
<body>

<?php include('header.php') ?>     // didn't work
<?php get_header(); ?>      // didn't work

<div class="content"> </div>

</body>
```

PHP File :

```
<h1>TITLE</h1>
```

When i put the code directly on the page - it shows "TITLE"

When i try include or get_header , i get a blank page . I checked the codex and online posts but i've not been able to fix it .

Any help would be appreciated - Thanks

Comment: `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>` Try that. Concerning get_header(); is a wordpress function (or whatever other platform use it)

Comment: There could be many reasons why you're seeing a blank page.  How are you previewing your page?  Are you using the file:// protocol, localhost, or web server?

Comment: localhost/url - using xampp on my pc

Comment: If you're using XAMPP, I'm guessing your site is under `htdocs/url`...  You've mentioned you're using an HTML file, could you verify that your files are using the .php extension and not .html? (I will unproudly admit that I've found files named index.php.html in the past.)  Also, check the XAMPP Control Panel to ensure Apache is running.

Comment: @John_Nil instead of using `include()`, use `require()`.  PHP will spit out an error, which will probably tell you why it's not displaying. :).

Comment: Found a way to make it work -

I changed my index.html to index.php and it seems to be working now -

Is there any difference having a page with .php instead of .html ?

Thanks a lot for your help guys

Comment: @John_Nil a .php file can render exactly the same as .html, but does not allow the server to read `<?php ?>` syntax (it's important to understand that PHP is a server-side language, unlike HTML which is generally client-side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in your header.php:

```
<?php
echo "<h1>TITLE</h1>";
?>
```

Then where you want to insert the header:

```
<?php include '/header.php' ?>
```

The `/` character makes the path to header.php relative to your root.

Comment: Maybe in header php leave out the end tag ?> sometimes that's a problem depending on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include("dyn_layout/cbside_php.php"); ?>
```

This works for me... just don't forget to rename your files to .php extension... including the file where the insertion is made.